# How to manage activities in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

I identified a problem in changing one activity using tab. In one tab activity I'm adding data to my SQLite database, and in the other tab activity I am displaying them using listview(array adapter). But when I come back to add data after adding new items to SQLite, the newly added records are not updated in my listview.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be pulling the list data from a DB. Is there a reason why you are using an ArrayAdapter instead of a CursorAdapter?

Anyway, you should call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your list adapter when the data has changed so it can refresh the view.

Comment: hi friend the problem is the activity still in active mode, when i coming to that activity it not calling it any of its life cycle methods like oncreate, onrestart so method code is not activating at all

Answer (score 0):

you can add code to update your listview (via `notifyDataSetChanged` or some such) by overriding the `onResume()` method in your activity which is called whenever the activity is brought back to the foreground. 
See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle