# how to refresh a list view when the activity still in active mode

Tags: android

I have a ListView that contains some data from sqllite table.
the table is updated by some other process, and I would like to
refresh it's data.

I tried invalidate,
tried doing setAdapter() again and again,
nothing helped. it does not reload.
Should I close the adapter somehow and re-open it?

The strange thing is that if I open another activity, then go back -
it WILL refresh itself.

Comment: y dont you update your exist question regarding this matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324467/how-to-manage-activities-in-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() function. It might work.

Comment: i had a problem with refreshing GridView and this helped. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

if you are using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, calling `requery()` on the cursor attached to the adapter will automatically refresh the adapter and attached view.